# Can I use extensions for Joomla 1.5 in Joomla 1.6?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I tried to find the answer for this question, but I cannot find any helpful answers yet. 
I know extensions in Joomla 1.0 can work with Joomla 1.5 in Legacy mode, but I'm not sure in Joomla 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We  have needed some works to Convert ...!! here i had attached the link...!! I hope It  will be help to you...!!!
http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a 1.5 extension on 1.6 without at least some minor modification. Depending on the extension, you might be able to update just the XML manifest and have a functioning extension. In other cases you may also have to rewrite some code if the extension makes use of depreciated code.

[The Wiki page (in the official Joomla docs wiki) linked by Ram Kumar](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6) will give you all the info you need to upgrade an extension.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of changes has been put in Joomla 1.6. The components of Joomla 1.5 can't be used in Joomla 1.6 because of all the changes.

For more technical information see [Joomla Wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're a programmer,then the answer is no, they use a completely different structure, and for that matter you can't use a Joomla 1.5 extension on 1.7 also.

We often migrate extensions for some of our clients from 1.5 to 1.6 (and now 1.7), but it's a very painful process and takes some time (but it's feasible).